# Android: Download manager downalod when clicked on a link

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making an app for the website of my school. Ive managed to make an app which loads the site through the app. Now, what i want is that my app should be able to download documents whenever i link on the link through my app.
 here is the code of my app so far;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
   import android.webkit.WebView;
   import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private WebView mywebview;
 @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings websettings = mywebview.getSettings();
websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.slate.nu.edu.pk/portal/pda" );
mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

 }
 public void onBackPressed() {
if(mywebview.canGoBack()){
    mywebview.goBack();

} else {

}
super.onBackPressed();
}
  public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
 if(hasFocus){
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN );
}
}
```

Comment: why you are making app which only opens website... Rather you should open that website link in your app's browser.... That will also download files.

Comment: @karan can you please explain me the difference and how to open website's link? Im new to programming.